# No logro mostrar mis imágenes con PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-workbench

para todos, un saludo!!!!

Les explico, quiero guardar una imagen en mi base de datos, eso lo logre, no lo que no logro hacer es mostrar la imagen

Archivos creados para guardar la imagen y mostrar

1. subir_imagen.php
2. subir_imagen_modelo.php
3. subir_imagen_visualizar.php
4. tengo una carpeta donde almaceno mis imágenes, también en la base de datos.

este código seria para mostrar ya la imagen en el index

```
<?php
include(dirname(__DIR__) . '/AvisionV2/db/db.php');
include(dirname(__DIR__) . '/AvisionV2/session.php');




 $query_sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_img_post WHERE id_usuario = '$login_id'";
 if ($resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_sql)) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
           echo '<pre>'; 
           #$id_imagen =  $row['id_imagen'];
           $ruta_img =  $row['i_imagen'];

           echo $ruta_img;

           #header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
      }
 }
```

con el : `echo $ruta_img;`

Me imprime

```
C:xampp mpphpB4C1.tmp
C:xampp mpphp74EE.tmp
C:xampp mpphp79DC.tmp
```

y el index

```
      <p>imagen aqui</p>
      <div>
           <?php include 'subir_imagen_visualizar.php'; ?>
      </div>
      <div>
           <img src="upload_file/<?php echo $ruta_img; ?>" alt="">
      </div>
```

Esto ocurre cuando le doy Click derecho inspeccionar elementos

```
<img src="upload_file/C:xampp   mpphp79DC.tmp" alt="">
```

imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://github.com/ballsfox14/SubirImagenPhpMYSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mira en "subir_imagen_modelo.php"

Al almacenar la ruta de la imagen (i_imagen), estás almacenando la ruta del fichero temporal
$query_sql = "INSERT INTO tb_img_post(i_imagen,id_usuario,i_tipo_imagen)
VALUES('**$filetmp**','$login_id','$filenameext');";

Así que cuando recuperas la ruta almacenada, estas recuperando la temporal, que es lo que has almacenado con ese INSERT y no donde realmente queda almacenada la imagen.

Prueba a cambiar **$filetmp** por **$fichero_subido** que es la variable donde indicas la ruta completa al fichero almacenado.

Como en esa variable está la ruta completa, tendrás que eliminar del código HTML el nombre del directorio, o estará duplicado y no se mostrará la imagen.
 upload_file/" alt="">

Comment: Gracias, lo pude solucionar :D, con tu ayuda, cambien lo que me dijiste. y me funciono....